# Control the size of object in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am new in Three.js.

I need to implement one 3D screen in which there are many objects in sky and there is one scale in screen.

I can move the scale in up or down direction. When I move scale up then all objects come closer in endless manner and same when I move scale down then all objects goes far.

So ultimately I want the effect like I am moving in space and I am bypassing the starts.

So for getting this effect I have used Three.js.

The problem I am facing is the when the objects come closer to me their size is increased and when the come very close than their size become very large in size. I need to increase size for some fixed parameters. After that it should not increase the size of object when it come close to screen. How I can implement that?

This is the code of object rendering:

```
function renderobjects() {

if(speed != 0) {
    if(textArray.length > 0 && textArray[0].material.opacity == 1) {
        for(var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
            textArray[i].material.opacity = 0;
        }
    }

    camera.position.y += - mouseY * 0.01;
    if (camera.position.y > 60) {
        camera.position.y = 60;
    }

    if (camera.position.y < 35) {
        camera.position.y = 35;
    }

    camera.position.z = (camera.position.z + 8*speed);
}
```

Please provide me the solution by which I can restrict the size of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The OrthographicCamera may be of help to you, it uses parallel projection. You can then do your own selective scaling of objects based on your needs.